# Can't Access Joomla 3.10.12 Administrator Panel after Site Restore

Tags: joomla, civicrm.settings.php

I restored my site from an Akeeba backup and now I cannot access the site's backend administration panel.  Mysite.org/administrator opens the login screen, but I get a 500 error when I try attempt to log in.

Hosting provider: Hostmonster.com
Joomla 3.10.12
MySQL Version: 5.7.23-23
PHP Version: 7.4
CiviCRM Verson: 5.49.1

I created a new database and user for the Joomla restore.  I had a similar issue once before in a restore so I checked both civicrm.settings.php files.   Both files had the old db name, username, and password.  I've updated those files with the new db name, username, and password, but I still cannot enter the backend administration. I believe there was another step I took to get the backend working, but I don't remember what it was.

The restored site error log reports:

```
[02-Aug-2023 14:25:11 America/Boise] PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home2/name/public_html/domain/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php on line 265
```

The civicrm.config.php file located in public_html/domain/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/
contains the following:

```
<?php
define('CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH', '/home2/name/public_html/domain/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php');
$error = @include_once( '/home2/name/public_html/domain/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' );
if ( $error == false ) {
    echo "Could not load the settings file at: /home2/name/public_html/domain/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
";
    exit( );
}

// Load class loader
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register()
```

Having fixed this once before, but not remembering exactly how, I believe I'm not too far from getting this fixed.

How do I get CiviCRM to point to the new db name, username, and password?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

When I tried loging into the backend of my restored site this morning it worked.  I didn't change anything in any CiviCRM files after my previous post.

I'm not sure if a cache was cleared or what, but I have access to the backend again.

Mike

Comment: The file civicrm/packages/DB/common.php shouldn't exist since it's now under civicrm/vendor/pear/db. It sounds like you still have copies of older files which are conflicting. I expect you'll see it keep coming up intermittently since sometimes it will load the newer file and sometimes the older. See the paragraph after step 4 here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/#install-the-extension